# Trouble with calling a method in Objective C (Apple Documentation example)

Tags: objective-c, methods

I'm following along with Apple's "Programming with Objective C" document, the link being: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1

Anyways, I've gotten to the point where it ask for calling the sayHello method.

> "Create a new XYZPerson instance using alloc and init, and then call the sayHello method."

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYZPerson.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]);

XYZPerson *firstPerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init]; //Initializer element is not a lime-time constant
[firstPerson sayHello]; //No Visible @interface for 'XYZPerson' delcares the selector 'sayHello'

@implementation XYZPerson
- (void)sayHello {
    [self saySomething:@"Hello, World"];
}

- (void)saySomething: (NSString *)greeting {
    NSLog(@"%@", greeting);
}

@end
```

I believe I'm having a misunderstanding with how apple is explaining the work or just have no clue.

Wishing apple had these examples done for us to review over.

Comment: Are you implemented the XYSperson.h and .m the say way they did ?

Comment: Your `XYZPerson.m` should *not* have a declaration for `main`. Get rid of that line. Also, why do you have code before the `@implementation` line? That code must not be there.

Comment: This code is in the main.m file while i also have the XYZPerson.h and XYZPerson.m from the last chapter present and why is bad to have it before? The example is asking me to create a instance using allocate and init in the main.m file. Unless I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the code inside the main function. Right now you have the code just sitting in your file, outside of any function. It should be:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    XYZPerson *firstPerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];
    [firstPerson sayHello];
}
```

Also, according to the docs you should have a separate `main.m` file that has your `main` function inside of it.

Comment: While everything in your answer is good info, it doesn't actually address the actual problem of the question which is that the method needs to be declared in the .h file for `XYZPerson`.

Comment: Initially declaring it in the interface didn't get rid of the errors but opening the function did, thanks. Also all of this code is in the main.m file if thats what your talking about.

Answer (score 0):

As you can only access public functions which are declared in .h file with the class object.

> Kindly declare that function in .h file and it will solve your problem